# Konica Minolta scanner cannot send outgoing mail via SMTP. Can I decipher the correct settings without resorting to onsite IT visit?

Tags: smtp, email-server, authentication, exchange-2013, network-printer

I'm not the business network admin, and slightly over my head. Still I'd like to try to fix it.
Sorry if this is wrong forum... if so, maybe you can redirect me.
We recently made some network changes, breaking functionality for the scanner.

First, is it possible I can figure out the various settings on my own or is it likely
our IT people (who can be tough to reach) must provide them?

When I try to email scans, I get 2 different errors.
My email: **error 107 (Server connection error)**
Coworker email: **error 535 (authentication error)**

Does the first error indicate the server can't even be found?
That it finds it but can't communicate with it (wrong port?)

I have no idea what authentication the server required, if any.
Or whether it used SSL, TLS, etc.. I suspect TLS.
I believe our email server is Exchange 2013.

I can login to the scanner's web interface as an admin, and view settings.

[image: Scanner current settings]

Here's what I've determined so far.

• I think our smtp server and port setting are correct.
I can telnet into the server on port 587 and get a welcome message like
*"Microsoft ESMTP Mail Service Ready"* and I can issue some commands.

• I can send email from my work email address. If I access my email through the outlook web interface, I can go to settings, and then view some email server settings for POP, SMPT, and IMAP. This is where I'm getting the outgoing server, protocol, and port.

• My other reason for suspecting TLS protocol is, that was already plugged in there.
I've also tried disabling SSL/TLS.

• I've tried SMTP authentication both on and off. The user ID (not shown in pic)
matched the admin email. Is that typical?

• I am fairly sure admin email is correct. Not so sure on device email.
Is it possible to figure out the device's email from its web interface?

• We had no security certificate (I think?). I tried creating one just to see if it helped,
but then the browser kept giving me a certificate security error when I accessed settings.
So I removed it.

• Googling for similar problems, one guy suggested updating firmware and disabling
TLS 1.2 and SSL protocols, only leaving TLS 1.0 intact. I didn't update firmware yet,
not sure how. But I did try disabling those other protocols.

Does anyone see anything wrong or unusual in the settings, or maybe you can tell me
if getting two different errors indicates a specific issue? Maybe some way I can test in telnet? Most commands that I googled for sending test emails via telnet, didn't work.

Comment: The username and password appear to be missing.

Comment: Sorry, that's my error, I blanked them in my image just for security. The username was the same as the admin email, is that typical?

The password, I have no idea. One is saved, I think. I have no reason to think it was changed. The only odd thing about the password that I noticed is... in the scanner's physical interface (on the device touchscreen) password shows asterisks. In the web interface, it's blank. Not sure if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors `107 (Server connection error)` and `535 (authentication error)`, they seem be caused because of the network connection and configuration/incorrect account credential in MFP, here is an article for your reference, which mentions the possbile reasons that cause `107` and `535` error code(and common configurations for MFP): **[CONFIGURING SCAN TO E-MAIL FOR KONICA MINOLTA MFP](http://goofficecorp.com/support/how-to-documents/scan-to-email/)**

See if there were some steps missed during deploying MFP according to the above guide.

Comment: Thanks for the link... seems like my first priority should be to find out if the server requires authentication, and if so what the login / password are. Does anyone know if it's common for a SMTP server to NOT need authentication? Also, I'm told the email address we have as the admin address is not an individual mailbox, it's a group. As such, it has no password. Does that sound right?

Comment: Could you configure your mailbox in the Outlook successfully? What about using port 25 for SMTP authentication?